# How to redirect javax.ws REST Service URL to port

Tags: web-services, rest, tomcat, jax-ws, redirect

I run a Web Service on Tomcat Server and access url is localhost:8080/RESTJerseyExample/alg/.

I want to redirect the url localhost:8081. Can I do this ? and How can I do?

Thank you for your advise.

Comment: One option might be to use iptables. This [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/536576/nginx-how-do-i-forward-a-http-request-to-another-port) might help

Comment: One option might be to use iptables. This [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/536576/nginx-how-do-i-forward-a-http-a-to-another-port) might help